# How to make Custom shape Like this with Container in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-custompainter, flutter-custompaint

[image]

How to create this shape in flutter?

I tried custom paint but didn't achieve this result

Comment: short answer: you can't do it with `Container`, custom shapes like this can be achieved using the `CustomPainter` widget.

Comment: @Gwhyyy yes, you can do it with `Container` - check [ShapeDecoration](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/ShapeDecoration-class.html) class that you can pass to `decoration: ...`

Comment: You right, I totally missed it, thank you